How imports/libraries eg. android.app.Dialog are organized in Android/Android Studio?
I want to know, what kind of code are inside imports/libraries in Android.
I already know that Java or Kotlin code of the Android is compiled to smali and dalvik executable classes, but I am interested about that code which are interfacing (straigthly) with Android os.
Can I then for example create my own Android Application wirh Android Studio which shows an AlertDialog or whatever else with whatever content I want without using the import android.app.AlertDialog; but with some kind of direct root level android code (some same methods calling everything in Android)?
I look at inside SDK folder of Android Studio and happily found folders like java.lang... with an .java file at the end, but that .java file was very abstract and did not contain any interesting code, only empty methdods and a lot of comments!

about SDK/Android - its open source, so you can inspect code freely, e.g. in HERE
you can always use middle-button click on mouse (or ctrl + left click) on class name to jump into and read code. but Android framework is changing in time, every app have minSdkVersion and supports few versions. when inspected class changed in time and you use above way for check out source you will get empty methods file only, as Studio does not know which "version" of this class should be shown - from oldest supported OS version? newest? some middle? same as connected device?

Thank you, but it seems like also that code are abstract...

what do you mean by "abstract"? as this class isn't abstract at all, is usable...

Class with empty methods, I mean

I've just linked you an original class with source and also described why this class opened in AS is "empty"...

Thank you very much @snachmsm because of you helpfulness effort, but when I do what you say I still see as empty classes as before! Although I see at the same time banner at the top of my Android Studio project window saying: "Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8)" And under: "Android SDK sources for API 34 not found" (probably because of my sdk installation choises)! So as your logic the sdk version is now given => no effect! I also tried to decompile with JD-GUI but sadly with same output. More answers needed, please.

Or if is even possible that there is really no other code (Android OS interprets these empty class methdos etc. as they're excepted methods)? And/Or what I really see is only for Android Studio Code Editor.

YES, that how it works... if your project supports range of APIs, minSdkVersion != compileVersion, then AS don't know which file to show (from odlest? newest?) and shows a "mock" with all methods only, without body (as these changed probably in time). maybe there is an option to force use always newest, dunno... when I really need to dive into OS source then I'm using linked official repo or grepcode mirror (at first picking particular version)

note that this is for Android OS/framework only. when you import some library, by gradle, form jar, whatever - it is uncheable and when you import it in your code then you can do mouse-middle-click / ctrl+left-click to inspect its code

@snachmsm Android Studio always uses the Android framework defined in targetSDK. But source code can only be displayed if the sources package for the used targetSDK API level is installed (see Android SDK manager). Otherwise only the empty method stubs are shown if you open a class that belongs to Android framework.
